# How to iterate over a list of Strings and concatenate them in Kotlin?

Tags: string, list, kotlin

I have a list of strings such as:

```
listOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "+", "3")
```

And I want to concatenate so that I only get the numbers: `"1234"`. I first attempted using a for loop which worked.

However I was wondering if Kotlin had a way of one lining the whole thing using a nice one line like:

```
val myList = listOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "+", "3")
someConcatenationFunction(myList) // returns "1234"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution I have found is this (to be put like in a separate file):

```
fun List<String>.concat() = this.joinToString("") { it }.takeWhile { it.isDigit() }
```

So basically, what it does is:

- `joinToString("")` : `JoinToString` joins the content of a list to a String, the `""` specifies that you don't want any separators in the concatenated String.
- `{ it }.takeWhile { it.isDigit() }` : means that from the concatenated list, I only want the Chars that are digits. `takeWhile` will stop at first non digit.

And here you go! Now you can simply do:

```
listOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "+", "3").concat() // returns "1234"
```

Answer (score 8):

Just using function `joinToString()` conact all the list items applicable for both `Char` and `String`.
below is the eg.

```
val list = listOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "+", "5")
val separator = ","
val string = list.joinToString(separator)
println(string)        //output: 1,2,3,4,+,5
```

Other eg.

```
val list = listOf("My", "Name", "is", "Alise")
val separator = " "
val string = list.joinToString(separator)
println(string)        //outeput: My Name is Alisse
```

Comment: The goal is not just to print the String, but also to filter it. Kotlin's documentation is pretty good about `JoinToString` https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html

Answer (score 4):

You don't clearly said so but I assume you want to concat integers as long as possible (I.e. stop once an invalid string is encountered. The most straighforward way to do this:

```
val data = listOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "+", "3")
val concat = data.takeWhile { it.toIntOrNull() != null }.joinToString("")
```

Comment: This can give unexpected (I think) result on `listOf("1", "-1")` :)